# IBAction to subview to check if image is hidden

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ibaction

I am trying to check if a image of a subview is hidden or not, by clicking a button. The log does display but i cant get the hidden status of the image somehow.

Whats going wrong here? Hope u can help me!

Viewdidload:

```
SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 *subslide1 = [[SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 alloc] init];
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
subslide1.view.frame = frame;

// This works finaly
UIImageView *zwart = subslide1.imageZwart;
[zwart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageblack.jpg"]]; 
[subslide1.b1 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchImageZwart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_scrollView addSubview:subslide1.view];
```

The IBAction to check the image in subview is hidden:

```
-(IBAction)switchImageZwart:(id)sender
{
    SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 *switchactie = [[SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 alloc] init];
    UIImageView *wit    = switchactie.imageWit;
    UIImageView *zwart  = switchactie.imageZwart;

    if(zwart.hidden == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Image black is hidden!");
    } else if(wit.hidden == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Image white is hidden!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't say... :(");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that inside your `-(IBAction)switchImageZwart:(id)sender` method you create a new instance of `SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3` and checking its properties (the `UIImageViews`) instead of checking the actual UIImageView objects you created on `viewDidLoad:`. What you want actually is to hold a reference to `subslide1` and check that instead.

Ps. Since the button calling the check method is actually a subview of your subslide1, you could get a reference like:

```
SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 *switchactie = [sender superView];
```

**EDIT:** An example on your actual code:

in your .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 *subslide1;
```

in your .m file:

```
@synthesize subslide1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...
    self.subslide1 = [[SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    self.subslide1.view.frame = frame;

    // This works finaly
    UIImageView *zwart = self.subslide1.imageZwart;
    [zwart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageblack.jpg"]]; 
    [self.subslide1.b1 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchImageZwart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [_scrollView addSubview:self.subslide1.view];

}


-(IBAction)switchImageZwart:(id)sender
{
    SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 *switchactie = self.subslide1;
    UIImageView *wit    = switchactie.imageWit;
    UIImageView *zwart  = switchactie.imageZwart;

    if(zwart.hidden == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Image black is hidden!");
    } else if(wit.hidden == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Image white is hidden!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't say... :(");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i cant get this to work. I tried the sender superView but it still does not recornize the images :/ maby im doing something wrong with making a reference, i am still trying.

Comment: What's the base class of your `SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3`? If its not a UIView subclass, then I guess you could try to set a property in your .h file like: `@property(nonatomic, strong) SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 * subslide1`, synthesize it and refer to it like: `self.subslide1`. I hope that this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks again, i tried the property in the SubSlideHoofdstuk3.h like so: `@property(nonatomic, strong) SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 *subslidereference;` And then synthesize it in the .m file. Then try to call it within the RootSlide.m like so: `UIImageView *zwart  = subslidereference.imageZwart;` But this give me an error. self.subslidereference doesnt work either.

Comment: SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 and Rootslider are both UIViewControllers btw!

Comment: Did you replace your initializer also like: `self.subslidereference = [[SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 alloc] init];` in your `viewDidLoad` method? (or set to point to your initialized `subslide1` ?)

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the example code! But if i put this in `@property(nonatomic, strong) SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 *subslide1;` the .h file i get an error. The code above is from the RootSlider btw. Maby i could send you my sample project? Really struggling with this!

Comment: I've fixed it. I've left you some comments also to know what was wrong (there were just small tiny mistakes). Neat design also! Grab it here: http://cl.ly/2Z0L2p172X00271d3y0H

Comment: Hey man! Nice! Thanks a lot for the fixes! cl.ly seems to be down? Cant download the file. Design is a beta but thanks, hehe!

Comment: Works fine in my browser, but anyway here is on sendspace too:http://www.sendspace.com/file/jlwdan

Comment: Seen the comments! I still am a BIG noob, hehe! Thanks again, plz, would u delete the comment with the link because my files are in there? Big thanks again mate!